# how to add multiple attrs in Django forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

How can I add multiple attributes to an input tag in Django ?

Example: For adding a single attribute I can use this code

```
email = forms.EmailField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
```

But if I want to add 'class', 'size' and 'placeholder' attributes then what is the way of doing it in django forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
email = forms.EmailField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'myClass', 'size': 'mySize'}))
```

This is normal Python syntax (inside the curly braces is a dict and a dict can have unlimited entries), and I don't know, why it should not work.

Normally, when you have an API, where a dict is required, that is a clear sign, that multiple values are possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juergen. I am a novice in Python and Django but now I know. Thanks !

Comment: @S7H: You are welcome! For an experienced Python developer, one look is enough.

Answer (score 1):

email = forms.EmailField(
    widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'myClass', 'onkeyup':'get code();'}))